# Setting d3.js code to point to my .csv instead of #csv?

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, report, dashboard

I am attempting to build a dynamic report using d3.js and I am currently sourcing the report with data from a .csv file. However, an example I'm using uses `"#csv"` from a static csv list:

```
var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());
```

The `"#csv"` is static code written above it in the .html as follows:

```
<pre id="csv">col a, col b, col c
0,0,0
30,30,30
70,70,70
0,30,70
70,30,0</pre>
```

I want to replace the `"#csv"` portion with `myCSVfile.csv`, which is a .csv reported generated every hour for my report (which is a webpage dashboard). The `myCSVfile.csv` file will sit next to this `index.html` file in an IIS environment when I deploy it.

Here is the rest of the code I am using for concept. Credits to Gerado Furtado for being very helpful with this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        pre {
  display: none;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td,th {
  padding: 10px;
}
    </style>
    <script src="/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">foo,bar,baz
32,55,67
12,34,99
11,21,32
11,65,76
99,14,23</pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

    var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
        .domain([30, 70])
        .range(["red", "yellow", "green"]);

    var body = d3.select("body");
    var headers = Object.keys(parsedCSV[0]);

    var table = body.append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');

    var head = thead.selectAll('th')
        .data(headers)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(parsedCSV)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
            return Object.values(d);
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .style("background-color", function(d) {
            return colorScale(d);
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I attempt to switch the #csv to my actual .csv file, nothing happens. I am having trouble identifying the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I used a `<pre>` element (in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154780/5768908) to your last question) to store the data and `d3.csvParse` (or `d3.csv.parse` in v3) to read it is simple: I like using S.O. snippet to show the demos, but unlike [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/), I cannot save a CSV file in the snippet. If I gave you the wrong impression that this is a good practice, I apologize: it's not.

That being said, for using [d3.csv](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/README.md#csv), you have to pass the URL of your file and the callback. So, in your case, it would be:

```
d3.csv("myCSVfile.csv", function(parsedCSV){
    //your whole code here, from 'var colorScale' to 'var cells'
});
```

Please notice that, using "myCSVfile.csv", the script will look for a CSV **in its same directory**. If the file's directory is different, change the path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you again so much for your help Gerardo, I was able to use the code you provided me to accept my .csv data source :) And yes you're absolutely right, the path directory matter is understood fully.