# d3.js: How to populate cells with color for blank values?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using some d3.js code I've found that dynamically creates cells based off .csv files it parses. Within the cells are numeric values, if values are `x`, it displays one color, if values are `y` another color and so forth.

My pseudocode is as follows:

```
//Color ranges for values within the report:
//0-30 green
//31-49 yellow
//50+ red
```

Here is the code in question:

```
var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
    .domain([30,49,20000])
    .range(["Chartreuse","Yellow","OrangeRed"]);
```

The `.domain([])` is, or at least how I assume it to be understood, lists the values and says okay, up to 30 - use chartreuse, up to 49 - use yellow and up to 20000 - use orange red.

What happens though is my report will have blank values since it is an hourly report, but the cells still get colored in as indicated below:

[image]

I want to know how to specify blank values in the list in the `.domain([])` so that way the cells under the 9:00am column will be white or colorless.

Conceptually, I tried `[NaN,30,49,20000]` but that didn't work. Or `["",30,49,20000]` but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem can be solved with an `if` statement that evaluates a ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.

> In JavaScript, a truthy value is a value that translates to true when evaluated in a Boolean context. All values are truthy unless they are defined as falsy.

The "falsy" values are:

- false
- 0
- ""
- null
- undefined
- NaN

So, using the code I wrote in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41154780/5768908), let's define some values as empty:

```
6AM,7AM,8AM,9AM
32,55,67,
12,34,99,
11,,32,
11,65,,
,14,23,
```

And here comes the important part:

```
.style("background-color", function(d) {
        if(d){
            return colorScale(d);
        } else {
            return "white";//or whatever colour you want
        }
    })
```

So, this:

```
if(d)
```

evaluates to true only if `d` is not null, NaN, undefined, 0 etc...

It can be even shorter:

```
.style("background-color", d => d ? colorScale(d) : "white")
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var parsedCSV = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("#csv").text());

    var colorScale = d3.scale.threshold()
        .domain([30, 70])
        .range(["Chartreuse","Yellow","OrangeRed"]);

    var body = d3.select("body");
    var headers = Object.keys(parsedCSV[0]);

    var table = body.append('table')
    var thead = table.append('thead')
    var tbody = table.append('tbody');

    var head = thead.selectAll('th')
        .data(headers)
        .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });

    var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
        .data(parsedCSV)
        .enter()
        .append('tr');

    var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
        .data(function(d) {
            return Object.values(d);
        })
        .enter()
        .append('td')
        .style("background-color", function(d) {
          if(d){
            return colorScale(d);
            }else{
              return "white";
              }
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d;
        });
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
 
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

td,th {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">6AM,7AM,8AM,9AM
32,55,67,
12,34,99,
11,,32,
11,65,,
,14,23,</pre>
```

**PS**: Your threshold scale is not correct. In a threshold scale...

> ...if the number of values in the scale's range is N + 1, the number of values in the scale's domain must be N.